# How to hide the Column header in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, expression-blend, expression

I am using a DataGrid in Expression Blend but I just need to show only the registries and hide the ColumnHeader.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In the `DataGrid` there is a Header section where the field `Header Visibility` could be set to `None`.

Or in xaml for the `Datagrid` add the property

```
HeadersVisibility="None"
```

Answer (score 18):

Both **DataGrid** of namespace System.Windows.Controls and
**WpfToolkit:DataGrid** of Microsoft.Windows.Controls have the property

```
HeadersVisibility="None"
```

In the properties window of DataGrid you can indeed choose from the available options

```
None
Column
Row
All
```

But this doesn't appear in the Properties window of **WpfToolkit:DataGrid** 
So as far as I know, you need to type that in inside your .xaml file.

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None">
       ...
</WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
```

If you want I can post the whole UserControl. Is that useful ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be double posted, SO is being weird, but you can do this from code behind too.

C# code behind with a XAML datagrid named dg_Main would be:

```
dg_Main.HeadersVisibility = Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;
```

Doing this in code behind makes it easy to dynamically show and hide headers as needed.